# Qlikview calculation of range for frequencies

Tags: qlikview

I am given a task to calculate the frequency of calls across a territory. If the rep called a physician regarding the sale of the product 5 times, then frequency is 5 and HCP count is 1....I generated frequencies from 1 to 124 in my pivot table using a calculated dimension which is working fine. But my concern is :

My manager wants frequencies till 19 in order from 1..2..3..4...5..6.....19...

And from the frequency 21-124 as 20+.

I would be grateful if someone helps me with this.....Eager for the reply....

Comment: Can you post some code to show us how far you have gotten? You are more likely to get an answer to correct your code than asking us to generate it.

Comment: I cant paste the code....i wonder if i can use class function?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Class function in the dimension, to split into buckets:

> =class(CallId,5)

And the expression:

> =count(Distinct CallId)

You can then customize the output by adding parameters:

> class( var,10 ) with var = 23 returns '20<=x<30'
>
> class( var,5,'value' ) with var = 23 returns '20<= value <25'
>
> class( var,10,'x',5 ) with var = 23 returns '15<=x<25'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a calculated dimension.

If your data has one row per physician coming from the load statement below will likely work.

**Dimension** 
 - `=IF(CallCount<=19,CallCount,'+20')`

**Expression**
 - `=COUNT(DISTINCT Physician_ID)`

**Sort** 
 -  Numeric Value Ascending

If your data has to be aggregated, more than one call row per provider incoming from the load try above substituting below for the Dimension.

**Dimension** 
 - `=IF(AGGR(SUM(CallCount), Physician_ID) <=19,AGGR(SUM(CallCount), Physician_ID),'+20')`